# How to hide folder in NSDocumentsDirectory and disallow backup via iTunes & iCloud

Tags: ios, backup, nsdocumentdirectory

I create private folder in NSDocumentDirectory and i want to hide it in iTunes and disallow to backup.

In this question [How to hide folders created in Document Directory in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207495/how-to-hide-folders-created-in-document-directory-in-ios) people suggest to save in private directory.

But it's not ok according apple documentation   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

> Application_Home/Library/ You should not use this directory for user data files.

Before iTunes11 this solution was work for me

[Can I add the Do not Back up for the "Document Directory" for iCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316819/can-i-add-the-do-not-back-up-for-the-document-directory-for-icloud)

but now i see folder with private docs in iTunes.

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For hiding your app from iTunes file sharing, you can set the below key to `No` in your info.plist.

> Application supports iTunes file sharing

Alternatively, prepend your filenames / directories added the the Documents directory with a `.` to hide it without disabling iTunes File Sharing. E.g. `.folderName`.

Use this to prevent iCloud backup, from [Prevent Backup to iCloud,is following code correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558315/prevent-backup-to-icloud-is-following-code-correct)

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath:(NSString *)filePathString {
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathString];

    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [fileURL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;

    BOOL success = [fileURL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
                                 error: &error];
    return success;
}
```

And to prevent app backup from XCode Organizer when the device is locked, use this snippet

```
//************************************************************************
// Method for making files and folders secure
//************************************************************************
+ (void)makeItemAtPathSecure:(NSString *)path
{
    NSError *securingFilesError;

    NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSDictionary *attrs = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&securingFilesError];


    if(![[attrs objectForKey:NSFileProtectionKey] isEqual:NSFileProtectionComplete])
    {

        if(![manager setAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete                                                                       forKey:NSFileProtectionKey] ofItemAtPath:path error:&securingFilesError])
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem in securing files: %@",[securingFilesError localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem in securing files: %@",[securingFilesError localizedDescription]);

    }

}
```

For selectively hiding folders in iTunes try renaming the folder with a . before it, like **folderName** should be **.folderName**